# On cliking add new post redirect user to a custom page first

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, redirect

Probably my question title is confusing.

I want something like this:

1. I have custom post type
2. When I click on add new, I would like to go to a "select" page
3. The select page allows you to make a choice (by clicking the appropriate box)
4. You are then redirected to the standard 'add new' custom post type page. However, a custom metabox will be pre-filled with data based on the choice in step 3. The url would have a custom query variable e.g. "wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=my-box&box_id=3"

Ok, hope you understand me now, how can I force that before I go to add new page, to show that my "select page" ?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm - I have to wonder why you don't just have the selection that you would have on the first page be in a metabox in the add new page - and maybe make it appear top right ?

Given that the implication is that they could change the prefilled data anyway?

Failing that, a possiblity may be to 
1) add a separate menu item for your special page. (and/or remove add new )
2) submit of special page calls/includes  "add new" file if special fields prefilled in _POST or _GET variable
3) metabox function will detect the prefilled variables and display them as you wish.

Kind of like this - it has a "a new link" from a settings page.

http://webdesign.anmari.com/2643/initial-content-for-a-new-page-or-post-wordpress-pleasant-surprise/